# C# Reflection - Base Type error

Tags: c#, reflection

```
Expression exp1 = new EqualsExpression(SearchContentProperty.Language, 1033);
```

I need to do it in Reflection, Can u help me

```
 public class SearchContentProperty
 { 
     public static IntegerPropertyExpression Language { get; }
 }
```

In Reflection, I am able to get the Property, but it's base type is `System.Reflection.MethodInfo`.

Due to this I am not able to use this property for an argument of another class.

It's throws an exception:

> `System.Reflection.MethodInfo` can't be convert to `MyClass Type`.
>   Explicit Conversion is also not possible.

Comment: "this property for an argument of an another class" - shouldn't that state "of another method"?

Comment: please show the Reflection code you are using... BTW: it is a public property, why are you trying to do this with Reflection ?

Comment: MY aim is to invoke a constructor to create an instance, but the class name will be known at runtime. so that i m working with reflection. Can I get the Static peroperty with it's own base type in reflection.

Comment: Again: show the Reflection code you are using...

Comment: could you please properly insert your code, by using appropriate tags - i'm getting tired of fixing that :)

Comment: This `EqualsExpression`, does it take a delegate as it's first constructor argument? Most of the content required to answer this question is entirely missing.

Comment: string assembly = "Ektron.Cms.ObjectFactory.dll";
                    string asspath = path + "bin\\" + assembly;
                    Assembly run_obj = Assembly.LoadFrom(@asspath);
                    paraObj[0] = run_obj.GetType("Ektron.Cms.Search.SearchContentProperty", true, true).GetProperty("Language");

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are referring to the class member `Language`... that won't be a `MethodInfo` it will be a `PropertyInfo`. If it isn't that, then your code isn't demonstrating the problem.

The `PropertyInfo` will expose a [`GetValue` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx), this will get you the value as an object. To provide to a `MethodInfo` of another class, simply insert it in the correct ordinal of the [`object[]` that will be representing arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx).

You cannot pass the `PropertyInfo` to the `MethodInfo` directly, the `PropertyInfo` is not a *replacement* for the property value, it gives you *access* to the property value.

**Update:** I hate it when this happens. I've answered the first question, but now the question has changed making my answer look completely off the mark...

Comment: Yes It's PropertyInfo but the PropertyInfo's Base type is MethosInfo

Comment: @VinodKannan `PropertyInfo` base type is **`MemberInfo`**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx

Comment: Expression exp1 = new EqualsExpression(SearchContentProperty.Language, 1033);
I need to do it in Reflection, Can u help me.

Comment: @VinodKannan It is best to post a new question instead of asking questions in the comments.